# What is the most efficient way to store an object containing regular expressions: json or xml?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, xml

My Electron app needs to store into and retrieve from a sqlite db, objects like this:

```
{"name":"my regexp","regexp":/some\spattern/i}
```

(real objects are much larger and much more complex.)

I started by storing stringified object in a field, but since JSON.stringify() does not handle regular expressions and converts them to {}, I had to convert all regexps to strings, which stringify() then escapes. I end up with very convoluted code in many functions.

If anyone has solved this problem elegantly either with JSON or XML, I would love a good solution.

Comment: "Native" regex objects/literals like `/some\spattern/` almost exclusively exist in Javascript. There's no mainstream serialisation format that has a specific literal for regexen. You will pretty surely have to store them as string like `"some\spattern"`, and yes, the backslashes will need to be escaped as necessary according to whatever string literal exactly you're using. Your code should probably expect to receive regexen as strings and use them as `new RegExp(o.regexp)`. Whether you serialise your objects to JSON or XML is fairly irrelevant and up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend JSON over XML, it's more compact, and is human readable.

Building up on @trincot's answer, here is a solution if you want to get a valid JSON string from the regex, so that it can be stored natively in browser local storage or a NoSQL database; it also makes it obvious that a string is a Regex string:

```js
const replacer = (key, value) => value instanceof RegExp 
  ? '/' + value.source + '/' + value.flags : value;

const reviver = (key, value) => {
  let m = (typeof value == 'string') && value.match(/^\/(.*)\/([gimous]*)$/);
  if(m) {
      value = new RegExp(m[1], m[2]);
  }
  return value;
}

let o = { "name": "foo", "num": 99, "regexp": /some\spattern/i };
console.log(o);
let str = JSON.stringify(o, replacer);
console.log(str);
let o2 = JSON.parse(str, reviver);
console.log(o2);
```

Output:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "num": 99,
  "regexp": /some\spattern/i
}
{"name":"foo","num":99,"regexp":"/some\\spattern/i"}
{
  "name": "foo",
  "num": 99,
  "regexp": /some\spattern/i
}
```

Comment: The first line of the reviver function should read:
let m = (typeof value == 'string') ? value.match(/^\/(.*)\/([gimous]*)$/i) : false;

Comment: @SamuelThorval: Either way works. The evaluation in logical `&&` stops if the left side returns a falsly value. Better not use the `i` flag because the only allowed flags are lowercase: `dgimsuy`: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-regexpinitialize

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON. The `JSON` functions `parse` and `stringify` accept a second argument to influence the process.

Here are two such functions `replacer` and `reviver` which you can use in your calls of `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`:

```js
const replacer = (key, value) => value instanceof RegExp 
        ? [value.source, value.flags, "RegExp"] 
        : value;
        
const reviver = (key, value) => value[2] === "RegExp" 
        ? RegExp(...value) 
        : value;

// Example run
let o = {"name":"my regexp","regexp":/some\spattern/i};
console.log(o);
let str = JSON.stringify(o, replacer);

let o2 = JSON.parse(str, reviver);
console.log(o2);
```

Comment: This is precisely the type of solution I was looking for. Thanks a lot.